# MVC Display Offences List By User State

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am just starting learning MVC and I am stuck on this issue. I will appreciate if anyone has come across this before. Thanks

I would like to display the list by station. E.g Police of New-York can only see list of offences in New-York.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwEAX.png) This is the most recent change but still not working.

I would like to display the list of offences by the USER state.

At the moment I am displaying all the users regardless of their state id.

Comment: Add your code to your question by indenting it 4 spaces so it appears like code. Don't put an image of your code.

Comment: From the screenshot of code you attached it seems you are trying to pass model to view but you didn't declared/initialized your model, you need to declare model that you want to pass to the view before passing to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options that come to mind. One, you can filter out the offenses by iterating over them and pulling out only the values you need into a new list in C#. Two, you could edit the stored procedure to pass in parameters (such as a State ID or User ID) and then filter out the list of offenses returned from the database using a WHERE clause. Below is some sample code based on your image.

Idea One:

```
public ActionResult ViewOffenceList(int filterStateID)
{
    PageModel model = new PageModel();
    DBFile db = new DBFile();
    var details = db.Offence.ToList();
    List<Offence> filteredList = new List<Offence>();

    foreach (var offence in details)
    {
        if (offence.StateID == filterStateID)
        {
            filteredList.Add(offence);
        }
    }

    model.OffenceList = filteredList;

    return View(model);
}
```

Idea Two:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.fwsp_GetOffenceList 
    @FilterStateID TINYINT   
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.offences o
    WHERE o.StateID = @FilterStateID
GO
```

These are just some quick overviews of the two options that come to mind given my experiences. In general, grab the ID of the state you wish to filter on, and use that to filter out which data to actually display. It sounds like you may have a User object which may have an associated State which you could use as the "filterStateID" in my examples.

If you're just starting out I'd suggest finding some tutorials online and walking through them. Here's one directly from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?tabs=aspnetcore2x